# MySQL vulnerability bind address 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql, port-forwarding

Am I safe from MySQL access from another host **even** if they know the credential of my database, including the port?

As far as I know the bing port doesn't allow any remote access. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I safe from mysql access from another host EVEN if they know my mysql credentials and port?

I wouldn't say "Yes". It, however, doesn't allow remote connections.

It's very likely that you'll have some sort of application hosted on the same server. So, if you leave anything like phpMyAdmin or Adminer, an attacker can easily get in using your credentials.